# How to open Python 3.10 from cmd when I have 3.7 installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python 3.7 and Python 3.10 both installed on my computer. However, when I launch it from cmd by typing 'python' it launches python 3.7 instead of 3.10. Howe to launch 3.10 specifically? Also, I have Pycharm which currently runs on 3.7, so, how to run it on 3.10?

Comment: You installed Python 3.7, allowing the installer to put it on the path, but either did not check that option when installing 3.10, or it got itself on the path *after* 3.7 somehow (and Windows will start the first match it finds). As for PyCharm, it allows you to select a specific interpreter in the project settings, either the main installed one, or (better) one in a virtual environment for your project.

Comment: A solution is to use `pyenv` so that you can switch between different versions of python easily

Comment: use `alais` or give a name for python3.10 in environment variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your `PATH` variable to link to Python 3.10, currently you have it linked to Python 3.7

Search for Edit Environment Variables, click the Environment Variables, Go to Path, and edit python to link to the Python 3.10 directory.

Comment: Note that this, although it will work, will cause a mess when you uninstall the application, as the installer is not aware of these changes and will not revert them when uninstalling. Instead of manually adjusting the path, you might want to consider simply reinstalling with the appropriate setting.